# Is it safe to malloc on an allocated pointer in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm working on a C library and am trying to be very cautious about memory management. I have a function which allocates memory for a pointer, and am trying to cover the case in which the pointer is already allocated. I am wondering if I need to free the pointer before allocating over it.

```c
char *x = (char *) malloc(12);
// ...
free(x);
x = (char *) malloc(12);
```

I'm unsure if the `free(x)` is necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such thing as an allocated pointer.

`char *x = (char *) malloc(12);` declares a pointer `x`. Then it allocates 12 bytes of memory and makes `x` point to the 12 bytes of memory.

`free(x);` frees the 12 bytes of memory. `x` still points to the 12 bytes of memory which are now freed.

`x = (char *) malloc(12);` allocates another 12 bytes of memory and makes `x` point to the new 12 bytes of memory.

If you removed `free(x);` then you would be allocating 2 lots of 12 bytes of memory, and not freeing the first lot. Whether that is a memory leak or not depends on how your program is supposed to work - it's only a memory leak if you aren't still using the memory for something.

Comment: Of course you can dynamically allocate memory for a pointer `char ** p_to_char = malloc(sizeof(char *)): char * p_char = *p_to_char;`. Of course, nobody hardly does this

Comment: A pointer should not be regarded as still pointing to the previous memory after it is passed to `free`. Per C 2018 6.2.4, “The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.” So, after `free(x);`, x does not have a determined value. In common C implementations with flat address spaces, code may often behave as if `x` points to the previously allocated memory. But in implementations with complicated addressing schemes, the value of `x` may change. And in any implementation, optimization may make it appear as if `x` changed.

Comment: @Jonathan I didn't want to say "that would be a memory leak", because it's impossible to tell from the code here whether it's actually a memory leak or not. If there is another pointer pointing to the memory, it's not necessarily a memory leak.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The `// ...` could easily include something like `currentX = x;`

Answer (score 2):

Yes the `free(x)` is necessary. If you remove that you will definitely leak memory when you next `malloc(12)`. Now if the sizes are really identical, then I question whether you really need that second `malloc`. If the sizes differ, you could use `realloc()` and remove the `free`.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe, that's to say: you are not incurring in any undefined behaviour.  But you are leaking memory, in case you have not saved the address given by the first `malloc()`, as it should be `free()`d at some point later.

Not doing the `free()` is not dangerous, but you cannot recover from that state, as you lost the reference to the memory where that chunk of memory was, so you cannot return it later (it is **required** by `free()`)

If you don't control to return the memory you are given, and your program does this kind of behaviour, you can finally eat up all the memory available to your process, and this can impact your whole system.